# web service that can run in both Cloud and Standalone configurations

Tags: architecture, cloud-computing, multitenancy

My company develops technology for visitor management. We currently have 2 solutions, one that is in the field, running on on-site hardware. The other is cloud, running on the cloud and processing all visitor related thing remotely.

Management wants us now to build a 3rd product to retire the two previous products and roll them into one. A web service to handle all the data either on site (for robustness) or in the cloud (for simplicity).

In my mind, what I need is a web service to handle the data processing, and it just just be spun up on a local machine or in the cloud, depending on need.

Could anyone suggest some architectures to learn or read more about?

Comment: maybe have a look at docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you'd need at least an [application service layer](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) to encapsulate and expose the API corresponding to the domain logic of your visitor management API.  This will structure your architecture using a coarse granularity tha is appropriate for remote services (be it a local webserver or a cloud server).

It's difficult to advise you further, because you let no clue if the visitor management is a very complex functionality, or if it's just some basic features.

Eventually, you could be tempted to package your application as a [microservice](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) if it is very focused.  In this case, it could help to also using a general [API gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) to give you further flexibility for interoperating the service with presentation logic (e.g. server based, client based, etc...) or local services o fthe customer.

Comment: The visitor management has its own database instance, its running replication, its interfacing with hard ware, and in some cases manages 1000's of transactions at a time, so it's fairly complex package. However I fail to see why the specifics of the app that's running will change the response.

I like the idea of the microservices, it allows me to break the software into respective components, and then if people don't pay for certian parts, those microservices can just be spun down. I'm going to mark this as the answer but if you have anything else I should hear let me know